# How to create a HIVE table to read semicolon separated values

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to create a HIVE table that will read in semicolon separated values, but my code keeps giving me errors. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE test_details(Time STRING, Vital STRING, sID STRING) 
PARTITIONED BY(Country STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Answer (score 11):

For me nothing worked except this:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0059'
```

**Edit: After updating Hive:**

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u003B'
```

so in full:

```
CREATE TABLE test_details(Time STRING, Vital STRING, sID STRING) 
PARTITIONED BY(Country STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0059'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: I have no idea why that worked, `U+0059 ` should be capital Y. Unicode code point for semicolon (;) is `U+003B` and using it as `FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\u003B"` worked for me. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Hive interprets \uxxxx as decimal values, that's why (59 = 0x3B) works, a bit unexpected though.

Comment: We updated our cluster to a new Hive version. `\u0059` is no longer working, it's only `\u003B` now

Comment: '\0059' worked for me - I am using Hive 1.2.2

Answer (score 5):

The delimiter you are using is the cause for errors. Semi colon is the line terminator for hive which describes completion of hive query.

Use the below modified ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE test_details(Time STRING, Vital STRING, sID STRING) 
PARTITIONED BY(Country STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

This will work for you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on an hdinsight azure cluster.

Comment: Doesn't work, getting "expecting StringLiteral near 'by' in table row format's field separator".

Answer (score 0):

Is your text properly sanitized? HIVE natively does not handle quotes in text nicely.

Try using [serde](http://ogrodnek.github.io/csv-serde/) with custom separator (i.e. semi-colon in this case).

Comment: Ok I tried using this and my code is : 

add jar /home/wsyed/csv-serde.jar
create table my_table(a string, b string)
 row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
 with serdeproperties (
   "separatorChar" = "%"
  )   
 stored as textfile

but it doesn't really create the table it just asks for: "Display all 413 possibilities? (y or n)"